# How could I get the maximun value on a field on SQL Server without max?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the max value on a field of a table but I can't use max or any other aggregation function nor cursors. For example I need to get the max value of the field amount on the table Sales.

Comment: use order by column desc with SELECT top 1

Comment: example : `SELECT TOP 1 amount FROM Sales ORDER BY amount DESC`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use aggregation nor top functions

Comment: Please add this constraint to your original question. I take it this is not an actual problem, it's just an experiment or a rhetorical question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways:
**1.** Sort the column descending and get the 1st row:

```
select top 1 amount from sales order by amount DESC
```

**2.** With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct s.amount 
from sales s 
where not exists (
  select 1 from sales
  where amount > s.amount
)
```

Comment: It Works, Thanks a lot!